# Quarantine Rule in New York

Tags: usa, air-travel, international-travel, covid-19, new-york-city

I am planning to visit New York from Dubai (UAE) in two weeks' time. What is the Quarantine Rule in NY at the moment? Are tourist attractions open in NY?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you fully vaccinated? The legal guidelines have now started to diverge depending on vaccination status. If not, please postpone your trip until your vaccination is complete.

Comment: No, I am not fully vaccinated though I have taken my 1st Jab & recovered from Covid 2 months ago.

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship?

Comment: Pakistan! living in Dubai.

Comment: If you wait just a bit longer I think you will find much more to do.  Things are opening back up now  but I bet the picture will look even better in 6 weeks than 2. You will also have a much better picture of what vaccine requirments for activities will look like.  I don't know about NYC, but other major cities are requiring full vaccinations or negative test status to do certain activities.  It's also unclear if non-us /EU approved vaccines would be accepted (ie will russian/chinese shots be ok for vaccine passports?)

Answer (score 1):

From the [New York State](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/covid-19-travel-advisory) Covid Website:

> Asymptomatic travelers entering New York from another country, U.S.
> state, or territory are no longer required to test or quarantine as of
> April 10, 2021. Quarantine, consistent with the CDC recommendations,
> is still recommended for all travelers who are not fully vaccinated or
> have not recovered from laboratory confirmed COVID-19 during the
> previous 3 months. Symptomatic travelers must immediately self-isolate
> and contact the local health department or their healthcare providers
> to determine if they should seek COVID-19 testing.

So technically you don't *have* to quarantine, however it also says:

> CDC and NYS recommend delaying international travel until the traveler
> is fully vaccinated.

And from the CDC [After International Travel](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/after-travel-precautions.html), quarantine is **still** recommended for international travel for unvaccinated people.  (However IMHO there seems to be a grey area between being unvaccinated and having only 1 of a 2 shot vaccination.)

> After travel information for people fully vaccinated with an
> FDA-authorized vaccine or a vaccine authorized for emergency use by
> the World Health Organization:
>
> - Get tested with a viral test 3-5 days after travel.
>
>   - If your test is positive, isolate yourself to protect others from getting infected.
> - Self-monitor for COVID-19 symptoms; isolate and get tested if you develop symptoms.
> - Follow all state and local recommendations or requirements after travel.
>
> After travel information for unvaccinated people:
>
> - Get tested with a viral test 3-5 days after travel AND stay home and self-quarantine for a full 7 days after travel.
>
>   - Even if you test negative, stay home and self-quarantine for the full 7 days.
>   - If your test is positive, isolate yourself to protect others from getting infected.
> - If you don’t get tested, stay home and self-quarantine for 10 days after travel.

So while quarantine is technically not required, it is still the recommended thing to do.  In addition, traveling internationally is not recommended, and I'd say even more so if you are only doing this for tourist reasons.

---

As for tourist attractions, that is an unknown as I have no idea what you consider to be a tourist attraction.  For all I know you want to visit NYC to see the [National Museum of mathematics](https://momath.org) (which is currently closed)

Comment: Travel is 100% okay if you’re fully vaccinated (otherwise vaccinations are kind of useless) although there are some serious concerns over the true efficacy of Chinese and Russian vaccines. Same goes for people who have recovered from the virus recently.

Comment: @JonathanReez But only having 1 out of 2 shots isn't technically fully vaccinated.

Comment: @PeterM though some recent studies are suggesting that 1 shot + having covid is about the same as 2 vaccines.  Of course caveats are that this isn't a settled issue (the cdc still recommends 2 even if you've had it) and they are mainly looking at the pfizer and moderna shots, I wouldn't trust the science holding for chinese / russian shots.

Comment: @eps I haven't seen (or looked) for any studies like that, but I'd still hang out for both shots before traveling.